# Testing a REST server from Angular without mocking

Tags: angular, rest, testing

I know that I should test a REST server from Angular with a mock, and there are dozens of examples on the web how to do this. But assume I want to test a service on the real thing which I have full control over.

Here is the working mocked version:

```
describe('SgformsService', () => {
  let sgformsService: SgformsService
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController

  beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [SgformsService],
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
      })
      httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
      sgformsService = TestBed.get(SgformsService);
    });

    it('should return a single item when mocked', () => {
    sgformsService.getSingle().subscribe(
      (sg: SgFormsBase) => {
        expect(sg.id).toEqual(34)
        expect(sg.pat_no).toEqual(1704)
      })
      const req = httpMock.expectOne(
        'http://localhost:8000/getsingle/Endoskopie/1631/2019-03-19/arzt/0', 'call to api');
      expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      req.flush({
        id: 34,
        pat_no: 1704
      })
   });
});
```

How do I redirect this to use the REST server instead of the mock? The code below does not work because I don't know how to create HttpClient for `SgformsService`.

```
describe('SgformsService without Mocking', () => {
  let sgformsService: SgformsService
  //let httpClient: HttpClient

  beforeEach(function() {
  //  httpClient = new HttpClient()
  //  sgformsService = new SgformsService(httpClient);
  });

  // https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests
  it('should return a single item from server',
    (done: DoneFn) => {
      sgformsService.getSingle().subscribe(
      (sg: SgFormsBase) => {
        expect(sg.id).toEqual(34)
        expect(sg.pat_no).toEqual(1704)
        done()
      });
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you need to create the `HttpClient`? Can't you just let the DI container take care of it for you(by adding HttpClientModule as an import) as it does with the actual implementation?

Comment: 1. Replace `HttpClientTestingModule` with `HttpClientModule`. 2. Remove anything related to `httpMock`.

Answer (score 1):

For the reference of others, and with the help of @peinarydevelopment and @Igor:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { SgformsService } from './sgforms.service';
import { SgFormsBase } from './sgforms-base';

describe('SgformsService', () => {
  let sgformsService: SgformsService

  beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [SgformsService],
        imports: [HttpClientModule]
      })
      sgformsService = TestBed.get(SgformsService);
  });
  it('should return a single item', done =>  {
      sgformsService.getSingle().subscribe(
        (sg: SgFormsBase) => {
          expect(sg[0].id).toEqual(7)
          expect(sg[0].pat_no).toEqual(1631)
          done()
        });
      })
})
```

The `done` construct is required if you want to use `expect`. If you only want to quick-and-dirty log the result, `done` is not needed.

See also https://angular.io/guide/testing#service-tests